# Why inheriting a constant variable in systemverilog does not work

Tags: inheritance, compiler-errors, system-verilog

What is wrong with the following code.

```
program test;

class a;
    const int i;
endclass : a

class b extends a;
    function new();
        i = 10;
    endfunction : new
endclass : b

class c extends a;
    function new();
        i = 100;
    endfunction : new
endclass : c

initial begin
    b bo = new();
    c co = new();
    $display(bo.i, co.i);
end

endprogram : test
```

I get the following compile error

> Invalid initialization of instance constant: 'i' cannot be initialized
>
> more  than once in constructor. There is a potential re-initialization
>
> at  statement : this.i = 10; Previous at: test.sv,9 Source info:
>
> this.i = 10;

Comment: My question is different. Won't the both inherited classes get a copy each of the constant variable

Answer (score 1):

You can only make one assignment to a `const` variable during the construction the the class object. That has to come as either part of its declaration, or assigned during its it corresponding constructor method. Even though you didn't write an explicit constructor method in `class a`, SystemVerilog creates an implicit one for you. You did neither, so its initial value is 0. The only way to override an instance constant's value is by passing it as a constructor argument, or parameterization.

```
class a;
    const int i;
    function new(int aa = 10);
      i = aa;
    endfunction
endclass : a

class b extends a;
    function new(int aa=100);
        super.new(aa); // super.new(); is implicitly added if you don't
    endfunction : new
endclass : b
class c extends b;
    function new();
        super.new(500); // super.new(); is implicitly added if you don't
    endfunction : new
endclass : b
```

Also note that it is now illegal to initialize variables when they are implicitly declared as `static` varibles inside procedural code. You should move them outside the begin/end block, or add an explicit lifetime  using the `static` or `automatic` keywords.

```
b bo = new();

initial begin
    static c co = new();
    $display(bo.i, co.i);
end
```

It makes a big difference of the declaration was inside a procedural loop.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I got it working now. However, I do not understand the edit you made `program` -> `module` and the stuff with `static` or `automatic`. I got it working with just `super.new(10)` and `super.new(100)`

Comment: https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/function-arguments-not-initializing-variable-inside-body#reply-54684